# VMware WorkStation - Bridge - Host IP Address Is Static & Public

Tags: vmware-workstation, bridge, static-ip

I am working on **VMware WorkStation 10**.
Main pc that VMware has been installed on it, is Windows 7 = Host = System **A**.
I have installed a Virtual Machine (Linux Kernel Base Operating System) on VMware = Guest = System **B**.

Now i want **B** system see the **A** system's inside network.
For this purpose i set Network Adapter mode of virtual machine (from settings) to **Bridge**.
Take a look at this link :
[VMware Interfaces Tutorial/](https://rednectar.net/2011/07/20/vmware-interfaces-tutorial/)
When the ip of **A** system is **Static/Dynamic & Private** every thing goes in the right direction.
For example **A** system's ip is like : **192.168.2.140**
In this situation when i Power on **B** system gets an ip address in **A** range ip address (**192.168.2.100**)
As you see in the link upper : In bridge mode **VMNet8** is involved.

---

But problem appears when **A** system's ip is **Static & Public** like ips use for the internet.
For example **A** system's ip address is like this :  **23.96.251.40**
In this situation when i power on **B** system, has a problem to get an ip address & sometimes it gets a version 6 ip address.
By the way i don't have internet in **B**.

---

How can i solve this issue? (Manually or Automatically)
Should i buy another ip for system B in A range ip address?
If yes give me a solution without buying an extra ip.

Comment: What IP do you expect B to get?

Comment: @bertieb Never mind, I just want B see the A's network & has internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your explanation was succinct and to the point. So much so, in fact, that I am surprised you don't see the answer yourself. Clearly, the source of your problem is outside System A, on the upstream DHCP server. But that's pretty much irrelevant at this point.

Your mistake is using the bridged setting, which is quite unsuitable for System B when System A is having a public IP address. You must understand that when System A is using the public IP address, it is part of the Internet. Hence, System B must have all the requirements of being on the Internet, i.e. a public IP. But of course, you don't want to fulfill those requirements. Hence, you should go with one of the other options: Host-only or NAT. If you configure them properly, you'll be able to have System B access the Internet and communicate with System A over a private IP address. The only downside would be System B being invisible to the Internet.

Because you didn't post any specifications of your local network, it is impossible for me to give you step-by-step instructions but I am confident it is easy enough with your level of knowledge to get the network working.

Comment: If i buy another ip can help or not?

Comment: Host-only or NAT > I want to send some packets to A's network & receive them from B system > So How Host-only or NAT can help about that?

Comment: This chat was useful - Thank you people.